# How to copy instead of borrow an i64 into a closure in Rust?

Tags: rust, copy, borrowing

I have the following minimal example of my code:

```rust
fn main()
{
    let names : Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![
        vec!["Foo1".to_string(), "Foo2".to_string()],
        vec!["Bar1".to_string(), "Bar2".to_string()]
    ];
    let ids : Vec<i64> = vec![10, 20];

    names.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i,v)| {
        let id : i64 = ids[i];
        v.iter().map(|n| 
            (n.clone(), id)
        )
    });
}
```

Now, when I compile that with `rustc` I get the following error message:

```
error[E0597]: `id` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:12:16
   |
11 |         v.iter().map(|n| 
   |                      --- capture occurs here
12 |             (n.clone(), id)
   |                         ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 |         )
14 |     });
   |     -- borrowed value needs to live until here
   |     |
   |     borrowed value only lives until here
```

But in my understanding, `id` is of type `i64` and should therefore be able to be copied into the capture, with would be exactly what I need?

I've also tried to inline the `id` variable but to no avail:

```
error[E0597]: `i` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:11:21
   |
10 |             v.iter().map(|n| 
   |                          --- capture occurs here
11 |                 (n.clone(), ids[i])
   |                                 ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |             )
13 |         });
   |         -- borrowed value needs to live until here
   |         |
   |         borrowed value only lives until here
```

So how can I copy my integer into the closure instead of borrowing it?

I tried using `move`, but `rustc` doesn't like that either:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> main.rs:10:17
   |
7  |         let ids : Vec<i64> = vec![10, 20];
   |             --- captured outer variable
...
10 |             v.iter().map(move |n| 
   |                          ^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

So I'd somehow need to get `rustc` to only move/copy some but not the other variable?

Comment: Use `move`. Copyable things are not moved but copied. Let me find the duplicate.

Comment: @Boiethios doesn't work either, I'll add the error

Comment: Add it to both your closures

Comment: I just answered, the question for quick help, Can be happily vote for if it is duplicate

Comment: @Boiethios Same error if I add to both closures. First version works like that as in AkinerAlkan's answer, but can I also get the second version to work that way?

Comment: It works pretty well: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95da9639666f29e055ab5fb75a912436

Comment: @Boiethios it doesn't when you inline `id`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de2261586d535305991492d18770bbc0

Comment: @Boiethios but as I understand, if I borrow `ids : Vec<i64>` I should be just fine getting one of the `i64`'s out and copy it into my return tuple?

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it "how to inline `id`"?

Comment: @Boiethios Well, I'm rather trying to understand why it doesn't allow me to write the code in question, especially why it says that `i` needs to live until outside the capture when the return value of `ids[i]` should not contain a reference to `i` anymore

Comment: Based on your error messages, you are still using Rust 2015. I **strongly** encourage you to switch to 2018 for improved error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a closure in Rust, it captures the variables either by value or by reference. A mix of both is impossible. By default, it captures by reference, but with the `move` keyword, it captures by value (*i.e.* it moves the captured variables inside the closure).

So, in your first code, you need to move `id` inside the closure:

```
fn main() {
    let names: Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![
        vec!["Foo1".to_string(), "Foo2".to_string()],
        vec!["Bar1".to_string(), "Bar2".to_string()],
    ];
    let ids: Vec<i64> = vec![10, 20];

    names.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i, v)| {
        let id: i64 = ids[i];
        v.iter().map(move |n| (n.clone(), id))
    });
}
```

Then you ask if you can "inline" `ids`:

```
fn main() {
    let names: Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![
        vec!["Foo1".to_string(), "Foo2".to_string()],
        vec!["Bar1".to_string(), "Bar2".to_string()],
    ];
    let ids: Vec<i64> = vec![10, 20];

    names.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i, v)| {
        v.iter().map(|n| (n.clone(), ids[i]))
    });
}
```

You cannot put `ids` at all in your inner closure, because you are already inside a `FnMut` closure (that requires exclusive access). Thus, you cannot borrow or move `ids` because it is already borrowed by the `FnMut` closure. Minimal reproduction:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = 0;

    let mut closure = || {
        i = 2;
        || {
            println!("i = {}", i);
        }
    };

    closure()();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the compiler points the error message to `i`, not `ids`, so is this just a wrong error message?

Comment: @msrd0 That's another issue: you try to return something that holds a reference to `i`, but `i` is declared from inside your mutable closure.

Comment: Ok I see, because `map` does take ownership of the closure, the compiler cannot guarantee it being executed before `i` runs out of scope. That was not very clear from the error message from the compiler. Thanks

Comment: That's not exactly that: `v.iter().map(<closure>)` returns a struct `Map` in which there is a reference to the local variable `i`. That's another case of a returned reference to a local variable.

Comment: I don't think your last paragraph is accurate. You *can* borrow `ids` in the inner closure, it's `i` that can't be borrowed (because it belongs to the outer closure). On the other hand, you can *move* `i` (because it's `Copy`), but you can't move `ids` because the outer closure only borrows it. You need to borrow `ids` while moving `i`, which you can do by [taking a reference to `ids` in the outer closure and using `move` to move both.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=196fe9c95c7abce220619c846ce7ed8e)

Comment: *A mix of both is impossible* — this is technically accurate, but as trentcl shows, you can take an explicit reference and then move the reference in, effectively getting a mix.

Comment: @Shepmaster You understand what I meant. You must add a step to have only movable types (either a copyable type or a reference). I answer to the question: why cant I inline the index stuff.

Comment: `FnMut` is also not relevant in the way you imply. Each closure will only borrow `ids` immutably if it can get away with it, even if it had to borrow the rest of the environment exclusively. Your minimal repro demonstrates a case where exclusive borrowing *is actually required*, but that's not true in the original code.

Comment: A mix of both is impossible - this is totally inaccurate AFAIK. Take a look at this very [simple example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6aa77d0b4e2fb3a3538151af72bf2b3). There is no hard rule saying that variables can't be moved into closure, it depends on how the variable is used. In fact some closures can be movable without using `move ||`

Comment: The trick in my example is that closure only implements `FnOnce` since the variable is always moved out of the closure's environment upon closure being called.
I don't think an example can be made for `Fn` and `FnMut`. Mix of both capture by value and capture by reference is only possible for `FnOnce` closures.

Comment: @MarinVeršić Didn't know this was possible. Feel free to either update my answer or create your own one.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the variable into closure with `move` keyword. Here you need to change the closure like:

```
v.iter().map(move |n|  // move is the keyword for moving variables into closure scope.
    (n.clone(), id)
)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c901ec00ddd6d4e41354badfbd59ff1f)