# Why doesn't a move closure take ownership of a variable?

Tags: rust, closures

[*The Rust Programming Language* says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.2/book/2018-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures):

> If you want to force the closure to take ownership of the values it uses in the environment, you can use the `move` keyword before the parameter list

What I have noticed with my code is that it won't take ownership of these values. The differences between my code and the given example are:

- using an integer instead of a `Vec`
- making `x` mutable instead of immutable

**Example 1:** *The Rust Programming Language*

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let equal_to_x = move |z| z == x;

    println!("can't use x here: {:?}", x);

    let y = vec![1, 2, 3];

    assert!(equal_to_x(y));
}
```

**Example 2:** My Code

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;

    let equal_to_x = move |z| z == x;

    println!("can use x here: {:?}", x);

    let y = 1;

    assert!(equal_to_x(y));
}
```

1. Why will example 2 compile but example 1 won't?
2. AWhy is the ownership of `x` not moved even if I explicitly write  `move` in front of the closure? Why is `x` accessible after moving it into the closure?

Comment: Because in your exemple 2, `x` is copyable, while it is not in the first one.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is given in the error message of your first example

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `x`
 --> src/main.rs:6:40
  |
2 |     let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
  |         - move occurs because `x` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 | 
4 |     let equal_to_x = move |z| z == x;
  |                      --------      - variable moved due to use in closure
  |                      |
  |                      value moved into closure here
5 | 
6 |     println!("can't use x here: {:?}", x);
  |                                        ^ value borrowed here after move
```

*"move occurs because `x` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait"*

This means, when a type implements the `Copy` trait (like an `i32` does), move copies the variable into the scope of the closure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does it make any difference if I remove the `move`? It will compile as well.

Comment: For copy types it won't make any difference at all.

Comment: @MariusRodi It does make a difference whether you use `move`, even for types that are `Copy`. Without `move`, the variable will be borrowed, possibly mutably, and with `move` it will be copied into the closure. In the former case, there is only one variable with a single value that is borrowed by the closure, while in the second case there are two completely separate variables – one inside the closure and one in the enclosing scope.

Comment: See also [How to copy instead of borrow an i64 into a closure in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54287719/155423); [How to force a move of a type which implements the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31168589/155423)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the reason is appropriately explained here.