# Why is the move keyword needed when returning a closure which captures a Copy type?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KnfGKn86s)

```rust
fn foo(c: char) -> impl Fn() -> i32 {
    || bar(c)
}

fn bar(_: char) -> i32 {
    42
}
```

Which throws an error

```
error[E0597]: `c` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:2:12
  |
2 |     || bar(c)
  |     --     ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
  |     |
  |     value captured here
3 | }
  |  -
  |  |
  |  `c` dropped here while still borrowed
  |  borrow later used here
```

I thought primitive types like `char` were copied by default; why do I need to explicitly `move` it (`move || bar(c)`) to get the code to compile?

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that the `char` is `Copy`, but what's tricky is exactly *when* the copy is performed.

Pretend that the `Copy` trait had a method called `copy`, similar to `Clone::clone`. As an example of what the compiler does, your closure becomes:

```rust
|| {
    let c = Copy::copy(&c);
    bar(c)
}
```

The closure only captures `c` by reference as that's all it needs to perform the copy when the closure is invoked. By returning the closure, you'd be trying to return the reference to the local, which is forbidden.

Using `move` forces the closure to capture `c` by value.

See also:

- [How to copy instead of borrow an i64 into a closure in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54287719/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423)

Answer (score 4):

> I thought primitive types like char were copied by default; why do I need to explicitly move it `(move || bar(c))` to get the code to compile?

It's actually *because* `char` is `Copy` that the issue occurs: by default, Rust closures are "smart", so the way they capture things is as unrestrictive as possible.

This means if they can capture by reference they will capture by reference, if they can't but can capture by mut ref they'll do that, and only if they can't will they capture by value ("move").

Here, because `char` is `Copy` it can be captured by reference then copied into the callee. And so the closure does that, and you have to tell it to capture by value (using the `move` keyword) instead.