# Why does moving a disjoint field capture into a closure differ when the type is a value vs a reference?

Tags: rust, closures, move-semantics

As explained in [Why is the move keyword needed when returning a closure which captures a Copy type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71767966/155423) and [How to copy instead of borrow an i64 into a closure in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54287719/155423), if a closure captures a type that implements `Copy`, we need to use the `move` keyword to eagerly copy the value:

```rust
fn use_move_to_copy_into_closure() -> impl FnOnce(i32) -> bool {
    let captured = 0;
    move |value| value > captured
}
```

As of Rust 2021, [disjoint capture in closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) means that only the specific *fields* used in a closure are captured by the closure:

```rust
struct Wrapper(i32);

fn edition_2021_only_captures_specific_fields(captured: Wrapper) -> impl FnOnce(i32) -> bool {
    let ret = move |value| value > captured.0;
    drop(captured); // fails in 2015, 2018, succeeds in 2021
    ret
}
```

If I capture a `Copy` field *belonging to a reference*, however, the field is not copied:

```rust
struct Wrapper(i32);

fn capturing_a_field_of_a_reference(captured: &Wrapper) -> impl FnOnce(i32) -> bool {
    move |value| value > captured.0 
}
```

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:15:60
   |
15 | fn capturing_a_field_of_a_reference(captured: &Wrapper) -> impl FnOnce(i32) -> bool {
   |                                               --------     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                               |
   |                                               hidden type `[closure@src/lib.rs:16:5: 16:36]` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
   |
help: to declare that the `impl Trait` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
15 | fn capturing_a_field_of_a_reference(captured: &Wrapper) -> impl FnOnce(i32) -> bool + '_ {
   |                                                                                     ++++
```

I expected that the field `.0` would be copied in, just like in the unwrapped `i32` or the owned `Wrapper` cases. What causes this difference?

Answer (score 0):

`move` captures the environment by value, but things in the environment that are references *remain references* -- the references are captured by value.

Put another way, `move` closures *only* try to move values, because otherwise there wouldn't be a way to simultaneously capture some things by value and some things by reference.  For example, it's a common pattern to do this when dealing with threads in e.g. crossbeam.  Assume these structs:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    pub fn baz(&mut self, _: i32) {}
}

struct Bar(pub i32);
```

And this snippet:

```
let foo = Foo;
let bar = Bar(0);

{
    let mut foo = foo.clone();
    let bar = &bar;
    s.spawn(move |_| {
        foo.baz(bar.0);
    });
}
```

Here the closure takes ownership of the clone of `foo` but references `bar.0`.  *This is true even if the type of `bar.0` is `Copy`.*

If it didn't work this way, there would be **no way** to express that the closure should own the `foo` clone, but borrow the copyable value `bar.0`.

Remember that implementing `Copy` on a type only means that an attempt to move a value of that type will instead copy. Since `captured` is a reference in your third example, capturing `captured.0` doesn't attempt to move the `i32` like it does in your second example where you have an owned value, and **if a move isn't attempted then no copy can happen.**

Comment: The whole section about *otherwise there wouldn't be a way to simultaneously capture some things by value* is true, but not obviously relevant to the specifics around disjoint closure captures. Can you cite an authoritative source that discusses that a capture *of a field belonging to a reference* should behave as if it were itself a reference, as opposed to behaving as if it were a value?

Comment: @Shepmaster I've never seen anything resembling a specification for all of Rust, so I'm not sure there _is_ much in the way of an "authoritative source." I've looked at both the disjoint capture section of the 2021 guide and the RFC, and none of the examples I saw there gave any impression that capturing a field by reference could copy the value of that field _implicitly._ Disjoint capture only deals with _which parts of values/borrows_ get captured, not directly _how_ they get captured.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm extrapolating from the [`move` keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html) docs: "Capture a closure’s environment by value." To me this means the whole of the environment is in the closure as it is outside of the closure. References outside of the closure don't _just become_ values inside of the closure.

Comment: s/capturing a field by reference/capturing a field through a reference/

Comment: [This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/closure-expr.html) is the closest thing I can think of to an authoritative source, and the text describing when values are moved/copied/referenced is vague. I think the only authoritative source we might actually get on this topic is a Rust developer.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a question of whether the copy occurs, but when it occurs. The copy only happens when the closure is called, not when it's defined (how could it be -- a `captured` hasn't been provided yet). Since the closure outlives the function call, it needs to know that its reference to `captured` will be valid when it's actually called precisely so that it has something *to* copy. Therefore it needs to be annotated with a lifetime tying it to the lifetime of `captured`. Thanks to lifetime inference, it's sufficient to simply add `'_` to the `impl` instead of needing to explicitly write `fn capturing_a_field_of_a_reference<'a>(captured: &'a Wrapper) -> impl 'a + FnOnce(i32) -> bool`.

Comment: This appears to be the same content as the answers to [Why is the move keyword needed when returning a closure which captures a Copy type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71767966/155423) — are you suggesting it's a duplicate? However, the code in this question *does* use the `move` keyword, so it's unclear how it would apply. *a `captured` hasn't been provided yet* — what do you mean? `captured` is an argument to the functions, not to the closure. It's provided equally in `edition_2021_only_captures_specific_fields` and `capturing_a_field_of_a_reference`.